# SO topics: complex vs. easy

Tags: discussion

So I have no idea if this has not been discussed to death before. If so, just downvote or point me to the previous place.

In my day to day work I always use SO to solve easy issues faster than with google. "What's the right incantation to make Foo do Bar?" And it is awesome for that!

But in my spare time I try to answer SO questions in my area of experience. I also try to ask some of the harder ones I encounter. And that is where I see a big disconnect: There are very few meaningful questions to answer! I actually got some great answers on hard questions here. But why are so few people asking interesting questions?

I think hard questions are a bit different to easy ones. They are not "tell me how to do X". They are "tell me about X" or "I am trying to do X. Tell me what I am missing". More like rubber ducking.

Can SO be/do both? How?

Comment: [You rent a hotel room. You put a book in the top drawer of the bedside table and go to sleep. You check out the next morning, but "forget" to give back your key. You steal the key!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/102937)

Comment: By the way, Eric Lippert says that, when he visits Stack Overflow, he looks at 100 or more questions before he finds one interesting enough to answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes. That was the state of things I described as not perfect. Your answer is funny and insightful. How to get Eric Lippert to have an easier time answering? That was my question. I do not want a snark battle. There are two very valuable parts to SO: better google/interesting things. Maybe it is impossible.

Comment: My point is that there are very few meaningful questions to answer in the realm of "tell me about X" because folks ask far more questions of the form "tell me how to do X."  That's all.  It's about the kinds of questions that people are asking, not about the kinds of answers we are providing.  To answer your query directly, people are not asking interesting questions because they don't have interesting questions to ask; they only ask questions about *what they want, when they want it.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree. And it makes SO very useful! I see you are a mod here. Thanks for all the great and useful work!!! It is the first time for me posting to meta. What I am asking is: Is there a way or need to fix this? What I get from your answer is that there is no need to fix what is not broken.

Comment: One idea to fix this (not that it's very likely to happen)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use

Comment: "But why are so few people asking interesting questions?" - please define "interesting".

Comment: @gim interesting: not clueless crap like debug-this-code-for-me or I-dug-up-this-code-somewhere-and-need-you-to-change-it-so-it-does-x and not the 4365th question on C file IO

Comment: @dandan78 agreed on the first, but the second example you give is only not interesting if you've seen multiple of those 4365 questions. If the 4366th iteration of it is the first one you read, its interesting - to you. And that was probably the point I was hoping to make a month ago - interest is a personal thing.

Comment: @Gimby It's really not about me or you, but the site as a whole. Dupes diminish the usefulness of the site because they add nothing but noise. They can be useful sometimes, when a question is asked in a slightly different way, thereby providing new search terms for Google, but there are basic questions that I see asked again and again *every single day*. That's just failure to search and worthy of both a close vote and a downvote.

Comment: @dandan78 Now you're shifting the focus to site rules and that is a completely different topic. I am done.

Answer (score 2):

There is a correlation between a users level of experience and the complexity of their questions.

More experienced users tend to solve their own problems by doing research and usually only post questions after they have exhausted all avenues. These are usually more complex and well written but they are also more rare.

Less experienced users tend not to be so good at solving and researching their own problems and will ask questions more freely. These tend to be less complex and often poorly written but far more common.